# Как загружается в память .XML Файл DOM C++?

Tags: c++, windows, xml, dom

Хотелось бы узнать на Примере от - [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765465(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
VariantFromString(L"stocks.xml", varFileName);    
pXMLDom->load(varFileName, &varStatus);
```

К какой функции ядра, идет обращение для открытия/чтения .xml файла, внутри метода - *pXMLDom->load* , к NtCreateFileA, NtCreateFileW, ReadFileA  , либо какой то другой ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71056/discussion-on-question-by-lighfusion-----xml--dom-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как набор WinAPI-функций, ответственный за открытие файлов, ограничен и содержит в себе слова `Create` или `Open`, то можно начать поиск со списка импортируемых API-функций. Для этого подойдёт утилита [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Чтобы понять, какая именно библиотека отвечает за DOM-загрузку XML-файла, изучим [ваш пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765465(v=vs.85).aspx) повнимательнее. Интерфейсный указатель `pXMLDom` указывает на экземпляр COM-класса `MSXML2::DOMDocument60`, порождаемый в `CoCreateInstance()`. Этот класс, в свою очередь, экспортируется библиотекой `msxml6.dll`. Соответственно, именно её и надо открыть в Dependency Walker.

Среди всех импортируемых функций только `CreateFileW()` из `kernel32.dll` удовлетворяет условию, сформулированному в первом абзаце данного ответа. А эта функция, скорее всего, вызывает `NtCreateFileW()`, если исходить из сходства названий обёрток и целевых функций.

> *Из [переписки](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42039023#42039023):*
>
> Я чуть более чем уверен что файл там грузиться, не стандартным `CreateFileW`, `ReadFileW`! Иначе бы в момент загрузки, при попытки удаления, файл бы ругался на «Используется процессом», а такого не было.

Указание `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` в качестве флага при открытии файла позволяет другим в дальнейшем удалять и переименовывать этот файл.